# Duplicate headers received from IIS in CORS process

Tags: web-services, iis, cors

I'm configuring a web service application that uses CORS on IIS 7.5.  Every time we add a custom header, whether it is in the web.config or in the GUI, it sends two copies of the custom header values to the client, thereby breaking the CORS model.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Experience-API-Version: 1.0.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,If-Match,If-None-Match,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consistent-Through, Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,If-Match,If-None-Match,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consistent-Through
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag,Last-Modified,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Length,WWW-Authenticate,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consistent-Through, **ETag,Last-Modified,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Length,WWW-Authenticate,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consistent-Through**
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2014 00:43:58 GMT
```

Note the duplication in Origin, Expose and Allow Headers sections.  Right now to prevent complication we are only setting this at the Web Site level, but it initially seemed to start off when we were adding these to our web.config file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - the vendor provided DLL that provides the web service was adding these headers in their binaries.  Once I removed these from IIS, the headers were only added once.